# How to look up the currency conversion rates for missing dates in Hive

Tags: sql, hive

I have a sales table and a currency conversion table

```
**sales**

id, amount, currency, sales_date
1, 100, usd, 2022-05-01
2, 150, usd, 2022-06-04
3, 55, usd, 2022-06-07
4, 75, usd, 2022-07-03

**currency_conversion_usd_cad**

conv_date, conversion_rate
2022-05-01, 1.28
2022-06-04, 1.26
2022-07-03, 1.27
```

If I were to do the following

```
select 
s.id AS id,
s.amount*cc.conversion_rate AS CAD_amount,
s.sales_date AS s_date
from sales s
left join currency_conversion_usd_cad cc
on s.sales_date = cc.conv_date
```

my result would be

```
id, CAD_amount, s_date
1, 128.0, 2022-05-01
2, 189.0, 2022-06-04
3, **NULL**, 2022-06-07
4, 95.25, 2022-07-03
```

Since there is no conversion rate value for the date 2022-06-07, the amount in CAD defaults to NULL. Is there a way where I can get around this and make it use the conversion rate for the last date where there is a conversion rate? Thus, the expected outcome would be

```
id, CAD_amount, s_date
1, 128.0, 2022-05-01
2, 189.0, 2022-06-04
3, 69.3, 2022-06-07
4, 95.25, 2022-07-03
```

As 55 x the previous day's conversion rate of 1.26 would be equal to 69.3

Answer (score 0):

You can use `last_value()`:

```sql
select s.id, s.amount * last_value(cc.conversion_rate) over (order by s.date) as cad_amount,
       s.date
from sales s left join
     currency_conversion_usd_cad cc
     on s.date = cc.date;
```